# How can i build pytorch from the source on M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, pytorch, clang, gnu-make, apple-m1

I tried to build pytroch from the source file as right now we can't install pytroch directly using pip.

So i ran few commands which are mentioned below:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git 
2. cd pytorch 
3. git submodule update --init --recursive
4. python3 setup.py build
5. python3 setup.py install
```

after the final command, i got the error :

```
Building wheel torch-1.9.0a0+gitaeaa91b
-- Building version 1.9.0a0+gitaeaa91b
cmake --build . --target install --config Release -- -j 8
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target gtest
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target clog
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target fmt
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target pthreadpool
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target benchmark
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target libprotobuf-lite
[  0%] Built target gtest
[  0%] Built target clog
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target c10
[  0%] Built target fmt
[  0%] Built target pthreadpool
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mkrename
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target common
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target libprotobuf
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target mkalias
[  0%] Built target benchmark
[  0%] Built target mkrename
[ 16%] Built target python_copy_files
[ 16%] Built target common
[ 16%] Built target mkalias
[ 17%] Building C object third_party/foxi/CMakeFiles/foxi_loader.dir/foxi/onnxifi_loader.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/mkdisp.dir/mkdisp.c.o
[ 17%] Generating ../aten/src/ATen/CPUFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/CompositeExplicitAutogradFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/CompositeImplicitAutogradFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/Declarations.yaml, ../aten/src/ATen/Functions.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/Functions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/MetaFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/NativeFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/RedispatchFunctions.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RedispatchFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterBackendSelect.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCompositeExplicitAutograd.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCompositeImplicitAutograd.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterMeta.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterMkldnnCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterQuantizedCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSchema.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCsrCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegistrationDeclarations.h, ../aten/src/ATen/CUDAFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterQuantizedCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCsrCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/core/ATenOpList.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBody.h, ../aten/src/ATen/core/TensorMethods.cpp
[ 17%] Built target libprotobuf-lite
[ 17%] Building C object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_global_deps.dir/__/torch/csrc/empty.c.o
[ 17%] Building C object sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/mkmasked_gnuabi.dir/mkmasked_gnuabi.c.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 17%] Building C object sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/mkrename_gnuabi.dir/mkrename_gnuabi.c.o
[ 19%] Built target c10
[ 19%] Linking C static library ../../lib/libfoxi_loader.a
[ 19%] Linking C shared library ../lib/libtorch_global_deps.dylib
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 19%] Building C object sleef/src/common/CMakeFiles/arraymap.dir/arraymap.c.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 19%] Linking C executable ../../bin/mkdisp
[ 19%] Linking C executable ../../bin/mkmasked_gnuabi
[ 19%] Built target torch_global_deps
[ 19%] Built target foxi_loader
[ 19%] Linking C executable ../../bin/mkrename_gnuabi
[ 19%] Building C object sleef/src/common/CMakeFiles/addSuffix.dir/addSuffix.c.o
[ 21%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 21%] Generating ../../../torch/version.py
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 21%] Generating ../aten/src/ATen/CPUFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/CompositeExplicitAutogradFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/CompositeImplicitAutogradFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/Declarations.yaml, ../aten/src/ATen/Functions.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/Functions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/MetaFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/NativeFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/RedispatchFunctions.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RedispatchFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterBackendSelect.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCompositeExplicitAutograd.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCompositeImplicitAutograd.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterMeta.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterMkldnnCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterQuantizedCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSchema.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCsrCPU.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegistrationDeclarations.h, ../aten/src/ATen/CUDAFunctions.h, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterQuantizedCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/RegisterSparseCsrCUDA.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/core/ATenOpList.cpp, ../aten/src/ATen/core/TensorBody.h, ../aten/src/ATen/core/TensorMethods.cpp
[ 21%] Built target mkmasked_gnuabi
[ 21%] Built target mkdisp
[ 21%] Built target mkrename_gnuabi
[ 21%] Linking C executable ../../bin/addSuffix
[ 21%] Built target arraymap
[ 21%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/init.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/init.c.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc.o
[ 21%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/convolution-output.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/api.c.o
[ 22%] Built target addSuffix
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/api.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/convolution-input-gradient.c.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object third_party/googletest/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/cache.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/cache.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/convolution-kernel.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/arm/uarch.c.o
[ 22%] Built target gen_torch_version
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/arm/uarch.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/fully-connected-output.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/arm/cache.c.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object third_party/googletest/googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/arm/cache.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/max-pooling-output.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/arm/mach/init.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/arm/mach/init.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/softmax-output.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/relu-output.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo.dir/src/mach/topology.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/cpuinfo/CMakeFiles/cpuinfo_internals.dir/src/mach/topology.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object confu-deps/NNPACK/CMakeFiles/nnpack_reference_layers.dir/src/ref/relu-input-gradient.c.o
[ 22%] Linking C static library ../../lib/libcpuinfo.a
[ 22%] Linking C static library ../../lib/libcpuinfo_internals.a
[ 22%] Built target cpuinfo
[ 22%] Built target cpuinfo_internals
[ 22%] Building CXX object third_party/benchmark/src/CMakeFiles/benchmark_main.dir/benchmark_main.cc.o
[ 22%] Linking C static library ../../lib/libnnpack_reference_layers.a
[ 22%] Building CXX object c10/benchmark/CMakeFiles/c10_intrusive_ptr_benchmark.dir/intrusive_ptr_benchmark.cpp.o
[ 22%] Built target nnpack_reference_layers
[ 22%] Linking CXX static library ../../../../lib/libgtest_main.a
[ 22%] Built target renamePURECFMA_SCALAR.h_generated
[ 22%] Built target renamePUREC_SCALAR.h_generated
[ 22%] Built target gtest_main
[ 22%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum.cc.o
[ 22%] Built target renameADVSIMDNOFMA.h_generated
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libbenchmark_main.a
[ 23%] Built target benchmark_main
[ 23%] Built target renameADVSIMD.h_generated
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_extension.cc.o
[ 23%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/c10_intrusive_ptr_benchmark
[ 23%] Built target c10_intrusive_ptr_benchmark
[ 23%] Generating alias_advsimd.h
[ 23%] Built target alias_advsimd.h_generated
[ 23%] Built target renameSVE.h_generated
[ 23%] Built target renameSVENOFMA.h_generated
[ 23%] Building C object sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/sleefdetadvsimd.dir/sleefsimdsp.c.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building C object sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/sleefdetadvsimd.dir/sleefsimddp.c.o
[ 23%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libgmock.a
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_file.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.cc.o
[ 23%] Built target gmock
[ 23%] Building C object sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/sleefsvenofma.dir/sleefsimdsp.c.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpu=neon' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
[ 23%] Built target sleefdetadvsimd
[ 23%] Built target headers
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_helpers.cc.o
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin20.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/d0/f685f_rj5dqdy0876td4bqz00000gn/T/sleefsimdsp-dd8ced.c
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/d0/f685f_rj5dqdy0876td4bqz00000gn/T/sleefsimdsp-dd8ced.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/aman/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
gmake[2]: *** [sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/sleefsvenofma.dir/build.make:81: sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/sleefsvenofma.dir/sleefsimdsp.c.o] Error 254
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7845: sleef/src/libm/CMakeFiles/sleefsvenofma.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_map_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_padding_optimizer.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_primitive_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_service.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_string_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_doc_comment.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_enum.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_enum_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_field_base.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_generator.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_helpers.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_map_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_message.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_message_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_primitive_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_reflection_class.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_repeated_enum_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_repeated_message_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_repeated_primitive_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_source_generator_base.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/csharp/csharp_wrapper_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_context.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_doc_comment.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum_field_lite.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum_lite.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_extension.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_extension_lite.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_field.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_file.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_generator.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_generator_factory.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_helpers.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_map_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_map_field_lite.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_builder.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_builder_lite.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_field_lite.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_lite.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_name_resolver.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_primitive_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_primitive_field_lite.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_service.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_shared_code_generator.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_string_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_string_field_lite.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/js_generator.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/well_known_types_embed.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_enum_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_enum.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_extension.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_file.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_generator.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_helpers.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_map_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_message.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_message_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_oneof.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/objectivec/objectivec_primitive_field.cc.o
[ 24%] Built target ATEN_CPU_FILES_GEN_TARGET
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/php/php_generator.cc.o
[ 24%] Generating ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_2.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_3.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/TraceType_4.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ADInplaceOrViewType_0.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/ADInplaceOrViewType_1.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/Functions.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/variable_factories.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType.h, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_variable_methods.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_torch_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_nn_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_fft_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_linalg_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_special_functions.cpp, ../../torch/csrc/autograd/generated/python_functions.h, ../../torch/testing/_internal/generated/annotated_fn_args.py
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/ruby/ruby_generator.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/subprocess.cc.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeFiles/libprotoc.dir/__/src/google/protobuf/compiler/zip_writer.cc.o
[ 24%] Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libprotoc.a
[ 24%] Built target libprotoc
[ 24%] Built target generate-torch-sources
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like your compiler died; it apparently has a bug.  Maybe you can use a newer version of the compiler and see if the bug is fixed.

Comment: Seems that Pytorch is not yet supported natively for M1 processors, however you can build the x86 intel version which runs via Rosetta 2 [like this](https://naturale0.github.io/machine%20learning/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch).